# ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have a web application in the following environment.

- JPA 2.0
- Spring 3.2.2
- MySQL 5.6.11
- Hibernate 4.2.0 CR1
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.35

My configurations until now in the `application-context.xml` file are as under.

```spring
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social_networking?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="WebAppPU"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="testDAOService" class="admin.dao.TestDAO"/>
</beans>
```

The `persistence.xml` contains the following xml.

```spring
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <!--<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.Test</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social_networking?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>-->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the following is the only entity class right now. I have tried to perform an insert operation with this entity which has been succeeded.

```spring
package model;

@Entity
public class Test implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "description", length = 45)
    private String description;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Test() {}

    public Test(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Getters and setter.
}
```

Although the application runs, the following exception can be seen on the server console.

```spring
ERROR: HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.<init>(DatabaseMetadata.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3926)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.reload(ManagerServlet.java:954)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Tried to use the following property inside the `persistence.xml` file but didn't help.

```spring
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're incorrectly mixing Hibernate dialects and databases. In your original issue you have a MySQL database and a dialect of `org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect` (see first code block below).

In your solution you have the MySQL database and the correct dialect of `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` (see second code block below).

If you had changed the `databasePlatform` in the original to be the MySQL dialect it would have worked as well.

---

Original:

```xml
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  ...
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
      ...
      <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
```

Working:

```xml
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    ...
    <properties>
      ...
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>      
      ...
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: `hibernate.dialect` in the last snippet should be replaced by `databasePlatform`. It doesn't work throwing an exception - `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?` (I have tried on Hibernate 4.3.5 final).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the reason was that the disk was out of space.

I have an instance on OpenShift, and first JDBC started throwing some exception because MySQL was down, filling the logs with garbage, and that filled the disk in the end.

Comment: So, did you slove this problem from then onwards? Are you using `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`? It is not a proper way of connection pooling. It returns a new connection everytime an application requests a connection. [**This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool Connections.**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html)

Comment: No, my stack is different, but the Hibernate exception is the same. I'm adding the answer to hint that the problem could be at unexpected place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in question vanished, when I insisted upon using a JNDI lookup. Accordingly, in the `context.xml` file, I have defined a resource like,

```spring
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/WebApp">
    <Resource name="jdbc/social_networking" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100"
              maxIdle="30"
              maxWait="10000"
              username="root"
              password="root"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social_networking"/>
</Context>
```

The resource reference needs to be defined in the `web.xml` file like,

```spring
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/social_networking</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

This datasource is referenced in the the `persistence.xml` file as follows.

```spring
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebAppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <!--<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>model.Test</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>      
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And finally the `application-context.xml` file has been modified as follows.

```spring
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="admin.mangedbean converter" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>  
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>            
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory" >
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">false</prop>
                <!-- I use fetch joins or queries/subqueries with a desired/required list of columns only for lazily loaded collections, when they are required to be fetched from outside of an active transaction boundary.
                     Therefore it is set to false. -->
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
              <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Bean registration-->
    <bean id="testService" class="admin.dao.TestDAO"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the table for entity exist.

If it exist then you get error for the below property.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Change it to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

This will create the new entity table.

Comment: Do not use this if you have some data in existing table. because create will drop your table and create the table again and you will be loss your all data

Comment: There should be some very large WARNING message that it will cause data tables drop